# On click add and remove background color for each div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I am new to Javascript and Stackoverflow.

I have multiple divs and on click they show and hide. Also on click a background color gets added to the buttons. Theres only one problem. I want it to remove the background color when you click on a different button. How can I accomplish this?

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("a.show").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
      $(this).click(function(){
        $($this.attr('href')).show();
        $('div.msg').not($this.attr('href')).hide();
      });
   });
});

$('.bg1').click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
});

$('.bg2').click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});

$('.bg3').click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
});

$('.bg4').click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

### HTML

```
<a class="show" href="#msg1"><div class="bg1">Hello Wolrd</div></a>
<a class="show" href="#msg2"><div class="bg2">Hello Planet</div></a>
<a class="show" href="#msg3"><div class="bg3">Hello Earth</div></a>
<a class="show" href="#msg4"><div class="bg4">Hello Everyone</div></a>

<div id="msg1" class="msg">
  <p>World World World World</p>
</div>

<div id="msg2" class="msg">
  <p>Planet Planet Planet Planet</p>
</div>

<div id="msg3" class="msg">
  <p>Earth Earth Earth Earth</p>
</div>

<div id="msg4" class="msg">
  <p>Everyone Everyone Everyone</p>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.msg{
  display:none;
}
```

Here is a demo of my code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrQpjr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. There are many many solutions to your problem.

You could tell all the other bg's to remove their backgroundcolor when the click event is ran for one of them. You could for example do this with an additional class `bg` that you add to all of the bg divs (bg1 - bg4). See working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWZBpz

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("a.show").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
      $(this).click(function(){
        $($this.attr('href')).show();
        $('div.msg').not($this.attr('href')).hide();
      });
   });
});

$('.bg1').click(function(){
    $('.bg:not(.bg1)').css("background-color","");
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
});

$('.bg2').click(function(){
    $('.bg:not(.bg2)').css("background-color","");
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});

$('.bg3').click(function(){
    $('.bg:not(.bg3)').css("background-color","");
    $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
});

$('.bg4').click(function(){
    $('.bg:not(.bg4)').css("background-color","");
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

```css
.msg{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="show" href="#msg1"><div class="bg bg1">Hello Wolrd</div></a>
<a class="show" href="#msg2"><div class="bg bg2">Hello Planet</div></a>
<a class="show" href="#msg3"><div class="bg bg3">Hello Earth</div></a>
<a class="show" href="#msg4"><div class="bg bg4">Hello Everyone</div></a>

<div id="msg1" class="msg">
  <p>World World World World</p>
</div>

<div id="msg2" class="msg">
  <p>Planet Planet Planet Planet</p>
</div>

<div id="msg3" class="msg">
  <p>Earth Earth Earth Earth</p>
</div>

<div id="msg4" class="msg">
  <p>Everyone Everyone Everyone</p>
</div>
```

Please note, this code is very long for what you're trying to achieve, it can be done with a lot less lines of code, but I'm trying to demonstrate it to you so you understand, without changing too much to your own code.

Here is a nicer, 'cleaner' solution. Feel free to ask any questions if you don't understand how this one works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMQpwm

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("a.show").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
      $(this).click(function(){
        $($this.attr('href')).show();
        $('div.msg').not($this.attr('href')).hide();
      });
   });

  $('.bg').click(function(){
    $('.bg').css('background-color','');
    $(this).css('background-color',$(this).attr('backgroundcolor'));  
  });

});
```

```css
.msg{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="show" href="#msg1"><div class="bg" backgroundcolor="green">Hello Wolrd</div></a>
<a class="show" href="#msg2"><div class="bg" backgroundcolor="blue">Hello Planet</div></a>
<a class="show" href="#msg3"><div class="bg" backgroundcolor="pink">Hello Earth</div></a>
<a class="show" href="#msg4"><div class="bg" backgroundcolor="yellow">Hello Everyone</div></a>

<div id="msg1" class="msg">
  <p>World World World World</p>
</div>

<div id="msg2" class="msg">
  <p>Planet Planet Planet Planet</p>
</div>

<div id="msg3" class="msg">
  <p>Earth Earth Earth Earth</p>
</div>

<div id="msg4" class="msg">
  <p>Everyone Everyone Everyone</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Add your code change on SO too, your solution is working but it is in link which is not good. Anyway +1.

Comment: Added both solutions (long ugly one and short tidy one) to my post.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really like the second solution. Is there any other of doing it without adding the background color to the html?

Comment: Also I get the first two lines of the code that when you click on the class bg it adds the bg color that is on the html. But how are the last two telling it to remove it?

Comment: Sorry if I am asking too much but is the my js code for the hide and show on the divs good? or is there simpler and cleaner way?

Comment: Sure, you can also put the colors in the javascript, but it's a lot less clean ;-). Here's a new example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZQpLj

Comment: The hide/show is OK. Again, there are many many ways to do this, but yours is fine. It's a bit double. You have a click-event on the `<a>` and a click-event on the `<div>`, but they're both the same thing that the user clicks on ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You may first add a `bg` class to every `div` (bg1, bg2, bg3, bg4):

Then you may use jQuery to toggle the css background:

```
$(this).click(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "initial");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit long winded as theres better methods of doing it but you can clear the bg color for all divs prior you set the bg color

**Jquery**

```
$('.bg1').click(function(){
  removebkng();
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
});

$('.bg2').click(function(){
  removebkng();
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});

$('.bg3').click(function(){
  removebkng();
    $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
});

$('.bg4').click(function(){
  removebkng();
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
});

function removebkng() {
$('.bg1, .bg2, .bg3, .bg4').css("background-color", "");  
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWZBKz)

A less code method

add the color you want as a data attribute next to the class eg

```
<div class="bg1" data-bkng="green">Hello Wolrd</div>
```

and then you can grab that in the code and set it

```
$("[class^=bg]").click(function(){
$("[class^=bg]").css("background-color", "");
var bkgcolor = $(this).attr("data-bkng");
$(this).css("background-color", bkgcolor);
});
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGdvwG)

Comment: Thank You. Do you know any better methods?

Comment: @Bryan -- Yeah a few, i added another in the Answer

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `background-color` of elements having `class` beginning with `bg` , that are not the currently clicked element ,  to `""`

```
$("[class^=bg]").click(function() {
    $("[class^=bg]").not(this)
    .css("background-color", "")
})
```

codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YweZjw